# What is the proper way to check for and handle null return values?

Tags: c#

I have some methods that return a value (or object) if all went as planned, otherwise return null (something went wrong).

For example, `DataTable dt = DoSomething();`  If something blew up in `DoSomething()` the return value would be `null` and `dt` would be set to `null`.

There are other cases where I'm testing for a value and then setting a variable to the value if the test value is not null. This doesn't feel right. I'm calling the same method twice.

For example, if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(getAddresss())) {Do Stuff;} If I declare a variable before the test, the code could blow up when it gets set. If I test, then set it seems like I'm duplicating work.

What is the preferred way to test for and handle null values?

Comment: If something went wrong, it is usually better to just throw exception...

Comment: I know this is not Java question, but Java is just 1 hop away from C#, so this does not matter. To solve this problem and problems related to this, Google employees have created `Guice 2`. Here is a into video, where thy explain the problems, how thy are solved and how `Guice 2` makes your life easier: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hBVJbzAagfs

Answer (score 6):

Throw exceptions from your methods instead of having them return `null`.

Regardless of where you stand in the almost religious arguments between return codes and exceptions, it's a fact that .NET is built on the premise of reporting errors by throwing exceptions. It would be really ill advised to follow a practice so detached from the rest of the framework for your code, if nothing else because of the unfamiliarity this will pose to others.

Comment: Totally agreed.  Return codes for failed operations are infuriating because they seldom contain the rich amount of information available in an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Is the duplication of work *that* important? It's all a null-check, after all (read: premature optimization).

I don't believe there's a shorter way, so just do the checks.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is to throw an exception in DoSomething().  That way, the actual reason for something blowing up can be logged, handled, passed on, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the coalesce operator (`??`) is pretty useful:

```
String myMessage = returnedValue ?? "Unspecified";
```

If the value being tested (`returnedValue` in this case) is not `null`, then it's returned; otherwise, the value on the right hand side of the operator is returned.

Here's the [C# specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) on the operator.

Answer (score 0):

Everything depend of the reason why the null is returned.

What you can do is:

1. [Use Null pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern)
2. [throw an own Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409563/best-practices-for-exception-management-in-java-or-c)

Answer (score 0):

[Code Contracts](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/) can help you in handling null values. Here's a short introduction http://devjourney.com/blog/code-contracts-part-1-introduction/